Cortex M self-protects its own MPU registers
Is it possible the Cortex M MPU to disable write access to its own registers for privileged code.
I want to setup the MPU once and disable MPU modifications forever. This will prevent someone to disable the PMU and get access to all memory.
I checked that and it do not work, i.e. the privileged code always can write to MPU registers.
Am I wrong?

Someone who can disable the MPU must have a privileged code. I'd suggest having a routine that cyclically checks the MPU registers and, if they don't match, makes specific decisions. It could even be a reset one of those decisions.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I don't really understand the question.  Privileged code can do anything it likes, that's kind of the point.  Why not instead design your system such that third-party code can't obtain privilege?  This is what most RTOS designs will do, and they will provide access to features that require privilege via system calls (usually implemented as SVC handler delegates).
